# Is it possible to overwrite a category method in a category of the subclass?

Tags: objective-c, overriding, objective-c-category

I know that one should not overide a method in a category.

I wonder if the following is possible. Experts in Objective-C are welcomed to answer!

1. I have two parent/child classes : `Class : ParentClass`
2. For each class, I have a category : `ParentClass(Category)` and `Class(Category)`
3. In each of these category, I have a method `-(void)additionalMethod`. The methods have the same name and are defined in the category (they don't exist in the classes)

Comment: You can try it yourself in 10 minutes. Why do you want to do such a thing?

Comment: I know it will compile but I wonder if when I call `[object additionalMethod]` with an object whose class in `Class` it will always take the right methde.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From ["Customizing Existing Classes"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html)
in the "Programming with Objective-C" guide:

> At runtime, there’s no difference between a method added by a category
>   and one that is implemented by the original class.

So the answer to your question is YES. There is no difference between overriding a method
in the subclass itself or in a category of the subclass. It makes also no difference if
the overridden method is implemented in the base class itself or in a category of the base class.

The only thing you cannot do is to use a category to override a method of the same class or of another category of the class.

Comment: Thanks @Martin R! Was it something you knew for sure or did you go and see in the documentation to check?

Comment: @Colas: Both (but I knew where to look) :-)